# 'Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid.'

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview, insert-update

I'm trying to insert some values into the datagridview using textboxes. The datagridview is binded to MS-Access database.

The datatype of the following columns is Integers: [Level_ID], [Paper_ID], [Year_ID], [Topic_ID], [Session_ID] & [TZ_ID].
And the rest are stored as string.

I have started my program by using:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data
```

Then I wrote:

```
Dim source As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='C:/Users/khuba/OneDrive/Desktop/CS-IA (Final-Draft).accdb';"
```

Then comes the code:

```
Private Sub Form8_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the '_CS_IA__Final_Draft_DataSet_X_.Question_Bank' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.Question_BankTableAdapter.Fill(Me._CS_IA__Final_Draft_DataSet_X_.Question_Bank)
End Sub
```

'
Then I created another Private Sub which handles the click of the Add New button:
'

Then comes the code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    QuestionBankBindingSource.AddNew()
    Question_BankTableAdapter.Insert(level_IDTextBox.Text, Paper_IDTextBox.Text, Year_IDTextBox.Text, Topic_IDTextBox.Text, Session_IDTextBox.Text, TZ_IDTextBox.Text, Question_gistTextBox.Text, Option_ATextBox.Text, Option_BTextBox.Text, Option_CTextBox.Text, Option_DTextBox.Text, AnswerTextBox.Text)
    QuestionBankBindingSource.EndEdit()

End Sub
```

I expected that the values written in the textboxes will be inserted into the datagridview so that I could save it later using the code:

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click

    On Error GoTo SaveErr

    QuestionBankBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Question_BankTableAdapter.Update(_CS_IA__Final_Draft_DataSet_X_)
    MessageBox.Show("Successfully Saved")
SaveErr:

End Sub
```

'

But the codes gives an error of 'Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid.'

Comment: Seems like you have an empty string that need to go in an integer variable. Try turning Option Strict On and properly convert your .Text into integers.

Comment: Try this out, `Dim id, paperid As Integer Question_BankTableAdapter.Insert(If(Integer.TryParse(level_IDTextBox.Text, id), id, 0), If(Integer.TryParse(Paper_IDTextBox.Text, paperid), paperid, 0) and so on...)` You need to try and parse the text to make sure it's an `Integer` type that matches your column definitions...

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what youre trying to cook there, but to add to a bindingsource list do this:

```
    With Bsource
        .AddNew()
        CType(.Current, DataRowView)("ColName") = TextBox1.Text
        .EndEdit()
    End With
```

Comment: For example take [Level_ID]. What I simple did here is drag and drop. I opened the data sources and selected the source I wanted to bind. Then I selected the Question_Bank table. From there onward,s I dragged the [Level_ID] text box and then dropped it into my form.

Comment: Try removing "Question_BankTableAdapter.Insert(level_IDTextBox.Text, Paper_IDTextBox.Text, Year_IDTextBox.Text, Topic_IDTextBox.Text, Session_IDTextBox.Text, TZ_IDTextBox.Text, Question_gistTextBox.Text, Option_ATextBox.Text, Option_BTextBox.Text, Option_CTextBox.Text, Option_DTextBox.Text, AnswerTextBox.Text)" And adding the values to the bindingsource as I have showed. Be sure you are casting from type string (textbox.text) to integer where applicable, IE such as your "ID" columns